# Derivation: Maximum entropy implies minimum energy

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, calculus

Callen claims in [his book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471862568) (chapter 5 in my copy at least) that the condition of minimum energy for fixed entropy is exactly equivalent to the condition of maximum entropy for fixed energy. I have seen this claim restated multiple times, and there are a bunch of answers in this site, like [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/338613/minimum-energy-maximum-entropy-equivalence), which directly cite Callen's claim and derviation.

I have some problems with the way he derives this equivalency.
Callen starts his derivation by stating that in the absence of internal constraints, $dS = 0$ and $d^2S < 0$ since entropy is maximum at this point. He then states that this implies that
$$
    \frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial X^2} < 0
$$
for all $X$. I understand he is roughly referring to the hessian of $S$, however, if this is the case, what he should probably say is that the Hessian matrix of the entropy $\mathcal{H}(S)$ is negative definite at that point, which means that $v^{T}\mathcal{H}(S) v < 0~\forall v$.

Callen finishes his derivation by stating that, since he can prove from this that

$$
    \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial X^2} > 0
$$
energy is a minimum at this point.

I don't think this implies the existence of a minimum, which, similarly to what was stated before requires the Hessian to be positive definite, which is stronger than all $\partial^2_X U$ being positive.

My question is twofold:

1) Does the partials $\partial^2_X U$ being positive imply that there is a minimum as Callen states?

2) If it doesn't then his derivation that the internal energy has a minimum at that point doesn't hold (as [shown here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_minimum_energy), in wikipedia for instance), what would be a correct derivation of this fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to be careful about what "the partials $\partial^2_X U$ being positive implies a minimum" means. If we mean that we have a given set of coordinates $X_i$ and that $\partial^2 U / \partial X_i^2 > 0$ for all $i$, then the claim is false. For example, a Hessian matrix like

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ -2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

has all $\partial^2 U / \partial X_i^2 > 0$ but is not positive definite.

But if we mean that if $X$ can be any coordinate at all, chosen from any coordinate system we want, then the claim is true: taking a unit vector $v$ in the direction of the coordinate $X$ (keeping all other coordinates in our coordinate system fixed), then

$$v^T \mathcal{H}(U) v = \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial X^2},$$

so that if **all** second derivatives are positive, the Hessian is positive definite and there is a minimum.

Thankfully, Callen's proof works for any coordinate system and any coordinate, so the claimed principle is true in thermodynamics.

Comment: Ok, I guess the question is not nicely formulated. The hessian being positive definite does imply this, but this alone doesn't guarantee a maximum, right?

Comment: I will edit the answer to try to make this more clear, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Ignacio edited accordingly.

Comment: Hi there! In your last line you write "Callen's proof works for any coordinate system and any coordinate, so the claimed principle". I wanted to confirm why that is so. Callen uses $X$ for arbitrary independent variables, so are you saying that in equation (5.3) we should actually be thinking of the two $X$ with respect to which the derivative is taken as different: i.e. as $X_i$ and $X_j$. And then use that if $0< \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial X_i \partial X_j}$ for all $i,j$ then we have a minimum?

Comment: Also, and if I am not mistaken, it seems in the derivation that $U$ or $S$ are held constant; thus is it fair to say that we are not saying that "where there is a local $S$ maximum there is a local $U$ minimum", but rather "we have a (local) maximum of the entropy at a given energy in configuration space if and only if we have a (local) minimum of the energy at that given entropy in configuration space." That is, it is a commentary about the equivalence of constrained extrema?

Comment: @EE18 Answering your first question: no, the derivative is a second derivative with respect to a single coordinate. The assertion is that if $X$ is any single coordinate in any coordinate system, then $\partial^2 U / \partial x^2 > 0$. That is, the second derivative is positive for *all* coordinates in *all* coordinate systems - but it's always a derivative with respect to a single coordinate.

Comment: And I think your second comment is correct, but as you can see this answer is pretty old so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: And just so I am certain, how does one know it applies for all coordinates in all coordinate systems?

Comment: @EE18 If I remember correctly, that's the assumption: the entropy being a maximum means that its matrix of second derivatives is negative definite, or that all its second derivatives are negative.

Comment: Oy, how could I have been so stupid. Thank you!

Comment: Hi there! May I ask if there is any mathematical theorem related to second paragraph :( Or i was wondering if you could explain why "But if we mean that if $X$ can be any coordinate at all, chosen from any coordinate system we want, then the claim is true"：should $v$ be any vector other than just a unit vector $v$
 in the direction of the coordinate $X$?